# TypeScript Array.from in IE11

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

***Array.from*** is an ES6 feature. When I use it in TypeScript and compile to ES5 target it does not change it:

```
tsc -t es5 prog.ts
```

i.e. when I look inside prog.js I still see ***Array.from*** in the same place. Using prog.js in IE11 complains as follows:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'from'

Why doesn't TypeScript convert ***Array.from*** in to some ES5 alternative?

Is there a way to set it up so it does?

Comment: It is a method that can be polyfilled. Language features that can't be polyfilled are transpiled.

Comment: I see. I did not know that. I expected transpiling to take care of converting all code to some ES5 equivilant. But, yes, it can easily be polyfilled. Thanks. Post an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a method that can be [polyfilled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill).

Language features that can't be polyfilled are transpiled (if possible on the selected TypeScript target).

Answer (score 12):

I would recommend using [`core-js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) as you'll get many more polyfills and won't have to polyfill APIs piecemeal.  If all you need/want is `Array.from`, then by all means rip it from the MDN site, but you can selectively import just the polyfills you need using `core-js`.

Using [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) to install `core-js`...

```
> npm install --save core-js
```

...then in your `.ts`...

```
import 'core-js' // to get the whole thing
```

or

```
import 'core-js/es/array'; // to get just array polyfills for example
```

Comment: Thanks. Your tip helped me a lot. BTW: actually, it's `import 'core-js/es6/array';`

Comment: it's `import 'core-js/es/array';` now

Answer (score 4):

The `Array.from` doesn't yet exist in TypeScript v1.8 so the compilator leaves as-is this part of code.

According to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/from) `Array.from` isn't supported on IE, so you have to implement a polyfill (see the link, the polyfill is in).